# What does "as such" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> These are used on medical devices to ensure secure leak-free
>   connections and **as such** require rigorous testing.

I looked up a dictionary, and the meaning was:

> as being what is indicated or suggested (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-such)

Then does it mean "These are used on (...) connections, and that's why these require rigorous testing"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These are used on medical devices to ensure secure leak-free connections and as such require rigorous testing.

I'll try to rephrase it as I understand it:

"These items are used on medical devices. Their purpose is to ensure that no leaks occur. **Being such critical items**, they require rigorous testing."

"Such" here stands for "such critical, such important parts". The importance is described in the first part of the sentence.